Python pyTelegramBotAPI: Setting a variable that is not affected by loops
I want to create a variable that is basically a boolean if the bot is working or not.
However, The script start to loop forever when using TeleBot.polling(), so if I set a variable in the beginning of the code like: is_bot_working = True, the variable will always be true and vice versa.
So, what should I do to set a variable that is not affected by the loops?
That's the code:
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

is_bot_working: bool = True

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def start(message) -> None:
        is_bot_working = True

@bot.message_handler(commands=['stop'])
    def stop(message) -> None:
        is_bot_working = False

bot.polling(non_stop=True)

